# Application of if condition to create text files in C

Tags: c, file-io

I am writing a program to convert CSV files to txt files. I have two CSV files to convert and I want the output files to have different names. Here is the program that I have.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#ifndef MAX_LEN
#define MAX_LEN (1024)
#endif

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
  FILE* fp;
  FILE* fp1;    
  int num, den;
  double result;
  char str[1000];
  char names[100][10] ;
  char line[4098];
  char filename[MAX_LEN];
  char textfile[MAX_LEN];
  const char * separators = ",";

  printf("Enter the CSV file name\n");
  fgets(filename, MAX_LEN, stdin);
  strtok(filename,"\n");
  printf("The CSV file to be converted to txt file: %s\n", filename);
 
  fp = fopen(filename, "r+");
  fgets(line, 4098, fp) ;

  char * token = strtok ( line, separators );
  int iVar = 0 ;
  while ( token != NULL )
    {
      strcpy(names[iVar], token);
      token = strtok ( NULL, separators );
      iVar++ ;
    }
  int NVar = iVar ;

  if (filename == "Equilibrium_trajectories.csv")
    {
      sprintf( textfile, "Chemical_equilibrium.txt") ;
      puts(textfile);
      fp1 = fopen(textfile, "w+");
    }
  else if (filename == "CH4_diffusion.csv")
    {
      sprintf( textfile, "Counter_diffusion_flame.txt") ;
      puts(textfile);
      fp1 = fopen(textfile, "w+");
    }
  else
    {
      printf("ERROR 404: FILE NOT FOUND\n");
      exit(0);
    }
```

And later I write something into the file.

The problem I am facing is no matter what, the if condition is not executed properly (so I think). Everytime I run the code, even though the "filename" is proper, my final output after the if condition is `ERROR 404: FILE NOT FOUND`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare strings using `==` (or `!=`), use `strcmp` because `==` compare addresses.